# phonegap-plugin-push Installation failed

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to install this new push plugin for cordova and phonegap:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push that replaces https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin. I'm using cordova and I'm having these two problems following the installation instructions of README:

1 - When I try install by

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

I have: 404 Not Found: phonegap-plugin-push

2 - And when I try:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push
```

I have Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push':TypeError: Uh oh!
Arguments to path.resolve must be strings

Comment: which cordova version do you use?

Comment: Thats the problem, you are using a very old version that doesn't allow install plugins from npm

Comment: Thank you, the problem is this old cordova version with the Android platform. When I created a iOS platform I didn't have any problem. I updated cordova and the installation ran ok.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the comments:

> Cordova version 3.6.3 does not allow plugins to be installed from npm.
>
> After updating cordova, plugin was installed successfully.